# Can we recognise our martyrs?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, users

There have been many complaints about the quality and friendliness of SO in the past, and there still are to some extent. However, over the past few weeks I've been noticing a trend in two particular groups of users.

Group 1 is the rep-hunters. I expect at least most people to have done some of this at some point: answering, asking as much as possible as quickly as possible to get the most rep possible. Works sometimes, others not. Often results in low quality answers...

But group 2 is our martyrs. I note this type of user particulary in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820348/what-is-defensive-reference-in-javascript), where @squint posted a comment. The OP responded by saying that this answered his question and if @squint cared to post his comment as an answer he'd accept it. Many people might have done so - but in this case, squint said his comment wasn't comprehensive enough and he would have to go away and research first.

Now this is not to make an example of either of the users involved here, or the question - it just drew my attention. However, this kind of person is the kind of person that IMHO we need more of on SO. So, is there any way currently to recognise their efforts? Obviously comments can be upvoted, but users don't get notified of this and it doesn't provide a tangible reward to keep them on the site.

If not, might this be an opportunity to create a badge? A badge awarded to users who show this kind of behaviour consistently (though I'm not sure of the system by which it might be awarded). Just a thought.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions (besides the badge which I don't think would be feasible to implement)? Also, what exactly is it that we would be rewarding?

Comment: We'd be rewarding the kind of behaviour that results in good quality questions and answers. Well-researched, well-written, helpful answers.

Comment: That's what's rewarded by the several badges which have to do with answers that attain some x number of upvotes.

Comment: Well, I get that but I mean you are talking about from comments? Or...? There already is a reward for well-research, thought out, written answers...upvotes and badges

Comment: One way to recognize another user is to place a bounty to reward an answer they've posted already. I've benefited from this and seen it happen to others too. I don't know how the badge thing would work. I've not looked at the list recently but as far as I can remember, they are awarded automatically and what you propose would require manual awarding. Or do you have an automated way to detect who is a martyr?

Comment: True. As I say, it was just a thought that we could recognise the most outstanding users who consistently show this kind of effort

Comment: @Louis - I don't know how the awarding mechanism would work and I'm not about to dump more work on the mods; suggestions are more than welcome

Comment: That's going to be tough to do.  If you remove the context (which the system can't infer), then you are left with two comments - one with an upvote and one without.  There's no way to automatically award someone this level of martyrdom, and there's no good approach to allow for others to attribute martyrdom.

Comment: I think you have good intentions but I just don't think what you are "proposing" is feasible.

Comment: `if person in lion_mouth: person.martyr = True`

Comment: I don't see this as a martyr, I see it as someone posting an answer as a comment. Unfortunately the issue with this is that unlike answers, you are unable to downvote comments. Something that solves the OP's problem isn't necessarily useful to other people (especially if the comment contains incorrect or incomplete information.) There's nothing to reward here if the poster is unable/unwilling to post a complete, correct answer.

Comment: I disagree with the premise of this post. I don't think the classifications are accurate nor does it seem that type of behavior should be encouraged.

Comment: @user3920237 I generally agree with your comment, but I can't help but find it ironic that you posted it _as a comment_.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Leaving a quick comment instead of a full answer is not the kind of behavior we want to reward. Sure, every once in a while someone leaves a comment that's good enough for an answer, but usually just barely. And most of the time even that isn't the case. Most comments are just comments, and a lot of those aren't even worth keeping around, much less rewarding with a badge or a little bit of reputation.

---

As a quick aside, there are a handful of words that really don't lend themselves to being used in an analogy. They have a very specific and *strong* meaning, and trying to use them to make a point just comes off as hyperbole. I think "martyr" might be one of those words for a lot of people. Using that word way overstates the ordeal of the people who don't get proper credit for their comments. Just sayin'.